# Is it possible to create a QR Code for an image using the python-qrcode library?

Tags: python, qr-code

I am trying to create a program that allows me to create a QR code for an image, such that anyone who scans it downloads said image. However, I am not sure that the library allows for such uses.

One issue I have figuring out is whether the image would need to be stored somewhere available for everyone, so that the QR code works.
Lastly, how would the user upload the image to the program? In case this is not possible, is there any platform where the user could upload the image and simply create the QR code with the link leading to the place the image is stored?

I tried using Google Drive, but I'm not sure whether that would work due to it always asking for access to the file.

Comment: QR-code is jut a string. It is has if you were asking "is it possible to write a sequence of characters for an image". The only difference between a text and a QR-code, is that text are easy to read for humans and harder to read by machines (it takes an OCR and some errors), while QR-code are hard to read for humans (not impossible: just follow the rules and decode it), and easy to read for a machine. But outside the ease for a machine to read it, it is still just a text. What the machine decide to do with this text is up to it.

Comment: Usually, when this text is an URL, most QR-code reader open the webpage whose URL it is (again, that is just what that QR code reading app decided to do with it). Some specific apps, for a given purpose, may take other actions (for example apps custom agents had to check for covid vaccine status, read the QR code, that is a string containing a bunch of information and ID, and check its validity).

Comment: Now for the image part, well, you can host your image on any server, and use a QR code to give the URL of the hosted image. It might work. Depending on what the app decide to do with that URL. It will probably work with most generic purpose qr-code reading app, since following URL is what most of them do. Or you could encode the base64 image directly in the QR-code. Without server. And, depending on what the app does when it sees such a base64 string, it might display the image. But size of image will be very constraint, since size of the string in a QR-code is not unlimited

Comment: So practical answer: yes you need to host the image somewhere, and then use QR code to write URL of the hosted image. That is what QR-code generator sites all do when they propose to create a QR code for an image.

Comment: Thank you! I think that gives me enough clues as to how I could solve this. I'll try hosting the pictures somewhere. What you said seems pretty interesting - I didn't know that QR-codes are essentially sequences of characters. That probably means that one could embed SVG into it, right?

Comment: @chrslg shouldn't you post that as an answer?

Comment: @AlenValdezSiller Put the image on a webserver and use `qrencode` to encode the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, I turn my comments into answer. Also, because it allows an answer to the follow-up question.

QR-code is jut a string. It is has if you were asking "is it possible to write a sequence of characters for an image". The only difference between a text and a QR-code, is that text are easy to read for humans and harder to read by machines (it takes an OCR and some errors), while QR-code are hard to read for humans (not impossible: just follow the rules and decode it), and easy to read for a machine. But outside the ease for a machine to read it, it is still just a text. What the machine decide to do with this text is up to it.

Now for the image part, well, you can host your image on any server, and use a QR code to give the URL of the hosted image. It might work. Depending on what the app decide to do with that URL. It will probably work with most generic purpose qr-code reading app, since following URL is what most of them do. Or you could encode the base64 image directly in the QR-code. Without server. And, depending on what the app does when it sees such a base64 string, it might display the image. But size of image will be very constraint, since size of the string in a QR-code is not unlimited.

So practical answer: yes you need to host the image somewhere, and then use QR code to write URL of the hosted image. That is what QR-code generator sites all do when they propose to create a QR code for an image. Because "image encoded as base64 directly in the QR-code" is not really a practical possibility.

Here is yet a counter example.
Starting from image
[image]

If I start with an enormous downsize, and drop of color
[image]

I can then turn this into base64 and then qrcode

```py
import base64
import qrcode

# Reading of image
with open('sunflower.gif', 'rb') as f:
    b=f.read()
# Turn into a base64 string 'encode/decode' may seems paradoxical, but they
# have nothing to do with each other. `b64encode` creates a base64 string, but in the form of bytes (a b-string)
# .decode() here is just the native python method to turn a b-string to a string
b64 = base64.standard_b64encode(b).decode()
# Add some decoration to make it a "URL" (a base64 URL, that is, that "links"
# to data that are directly encoded into the URL itself)
url = 'data:image/gif;base64,' + b64
# Turn this url into a qr-code
qrimg = qrcode.make(url)
# save the image
qrimg.save('myqrcode.png')
```

[image]

But see how huge is that qr-code (probably bigger that what is officially possible, tho all my qr-code readers read it correctly — not all can use it, but some does display the tiny black&white sunflower)

But, well, if I now just host the sunflower image (which I did, by posting it in this message, on imgur), and turn the URL into a QR-code

```py
qrcode.make('https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RVX0.jpg').save('hostedqrcode.png')
```

[image]

You get the full quality image with a small qr-code.
(But of course, you need to host the image first. And the user need to have internet to get it. When, with the base64 things, is local only: the whole image data is contained in the qr-code, it can work in plane mode)

Which answer to your follow-up question: can you do the same for svg. Well, yes. Same thing: you can either host/qrcode the URL. Or base64, and qrcode the base64 string.
With same difference: no limit to the size of image with hosting, even with small qr-code; while only possible for very small svg, and with huge qr-code, for base64 method. But well, svg files can be very small, if they are made of simple geometric forms.

For example, starting from this simple svg

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<circle cx="80" r="80" style="fill:#fd0; stroke:black; stroke-width:3;" transform="translate(200 200) rotate(0) scale(1 0.4)" />
<circle cx="80" r="80" style="fill:#fd0; stroke:black; stroke-width:3;" transform="translate(200 200) rotate(45) scale(1 0.4)" />
<circle cx="80" r="80" style="fill:#fd0; stroke:black; stroke-width:3;" transform="translate(200 200) rotate(90) scale(1 0.4)" />
<circle cx="80" r="80" style="fill:#fd0; stroke:black; stroke-width:3;" transform="translate(200 200) rotate(135) scale(1 0.4)" />
<circle cx="80" r="80" style="fill:#fd0; stroke:black; stroke-width:3;" transform="translate(200 200) rotate(180) scale(1 0.4)" />
<circle cx="80" r="80" style="fill:#fd0; stroke:black; stroke-width:3;" transform="translate(200 200) rotate(225) scale(1 0.4)" />
<circle cx="80" r="80" style="fill:#fd0; stroke:black; stroke-width:3;" transform="translate(200 200) rotate(270) scale(1 0.4)" />
<circle cx="80" r="80" style="fill:#fd0; stroke:black; stroke-width:3;" transform="translate(200 200) rotate(315) scale(1 0.4)" />
<circle cx="200" cy="200" r="40" style="fill:brown; stroke-width:3; stroke:black;"/>
</svg>

</svg>
```

That is, this image

[image]

But in SVG.

I can also host/encode (not in imgur this time, since imgur doesn't support svg).

[image]

Or I can base64/qrcode it, like I did with previous gif

[image]

Or even just qrcode the svg directly, without base64, since it is already ascii

[image]

In both cases, big qr-codes, but no quality loss this time, for the reason that this svg is already small enough. But as you see, it is a quite simple one, written by hand (a software generated svg would probably have been bigger).

Second method (directly encode svg) gives a slightly smaller qr-code. But drawback is that the qr-code reading app must decide to display svg when it sees that the content is a svg; like, in the first case, it must decide to display the url when it sees that the content is a URL. But since almost all general purpose qr-code reader do the latter, and almost none do the first, I would stick either on base64 trick (if svg is small enough, and it is really badly needed to have no hosting/no internet), or on hosting.